# Combobox That shows after the user press the yes button of a message box

Tags: excel, vba

```
If MSG1 = vbNo And MSG2 = vbYes And MSG3 = vbNo Then
MSG4 = MsgBox("Is the invoice Corporate?", vbYesNo, "Account Validation")

If MSG4 = vbYes Then
Related_to.Show

If Me.Related_to.Value = Royalties Then
MsgBox ("Whatever")
End If
```

Comment: Do you have a question? Also, if you are going to make your `If Statements` a one-liner, then you need to remove `End If`. When the If criteria and the Then statement all falls on the same line, this is what would be considered a 1-line `If... Then` statement.

Answer (score 0):

With your updated code, you need to make the following adjustments. If this isn't what you are looking for, then update your question to include an actual question.

```
Sub Test()

    If MSG1 = vbNo And MSG2 = vbYes And MSG3 = vbNo Then
        MSG4 = MsgBox("Is the invoice Corporate?", vbYesNo, "Account Validation")

    ElseIf MSG4 = vbYes Then
        Related_to.Show

    ElseIf Me.Related_to.Value = Royalties Then
        MsgBox ("Whatever")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It's your object that you provided in your original code. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? You have yet to provide any details on your problem.

Comment: I believe that my problem is that I'm working with a Combobox which is not par of the Module I working I'll put the whole code

Answer (score 0):

Sub account_validation_Issued()

```
MSG1 = MsgBox("Is the invoice X Related?", vbYesNo, "Account Validation")
MSG2 = MsgBox("Is the invoice ECD?", vbYesNo, "Account Validation")
MSG3 = MsgBox("Is the invoice Project related?", vbYesNo, "Account Validation")

If MSG1 = vbNo And MSG2 = vbYes And MSG3 = vbYes Then
MsgBox ("Unvalid answer combiantion")

ElseIf MSG1 = vbYes And MSG2 = vbYes And MSG3 = vbYes Or MSG1 = vbYes And MSG2 = vbNo And MSG3 = vbYes Then
MsgBox ("Projects: XXXX")

ElseIf MSG1 = vbYes And MSG2 = vbYes And MSG3 = vbNo Or MSG1 = vbYes And MSG2 = vbNo And MSG3 = vbNo Then
MsgBox ("Projects: XXXX")

ElseIf MSG1 = vbNo And MSG2 = vbNo And MSG3 = vbNo Then
MsgBox ("Projects: XXXX")

ElseIf MSG1 = vbNo And MSG2 = vbNo And MSG3 = vbYes Then
MsgBox ("Unvalid answer combiantion")

ElseIf MSG1 = vbNo And MSG2 = vbYes And MSG3 = vbNo Then
MSG4 = MsgBox("Is the invoice Corporate?", vbYesNo, "Account Validation")

Related_to.Show

End If
```

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Error(ByVal Number As Integer, ByVal Description As MSForms.ReturnString, ByVal SCode As Long, ByVal Source As String, ByVal HelpFile As String, ByVal HelpContext As Long, ByVal CancelDisplay As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

Select Case Me.MyCombo
Case "Royalties"
MsgBox "Make sure to enter comments for Above Target performance"

```
    MSG4 = MsgBox("Is the invoice Corporate?", vbYesNo, "Account Validation")

If MSG4 = vbYes And Me.Related_to.Value = Royalties Then

    MsgBox ("Whatever")
End If
```

End Sub